# htmlunit Socks Proxy not working with HTTPS

Tags: java, proxy, htmlunit, socks

I'm having a similar issue as [Is it possible to use HTTPS proxy in HTMLunit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689087/is-it-possible-to-use-https-proxy-in-htmlunit) , but I'm using httpunit version 2.10. The previous post was around the time of the 2.10 release ([changelog](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/changes-report.html#a2.10), so I don't know if anything has changed since then.

Specifically, this code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
ProxyConfig proxyConfig = new ProxyConfig("localhost",8080);
proxyConfig.setSocksProxy(true);
webClient.setProxyConfig(proxy);
webClient.addRequestHeader("referer", "http://www.google.com");
webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.setCssEnabled(false);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://somewebsite");
```

This should *not* work if I have no proxy running on 8080, but it does connect, just not through the proxy. In contrast, this crashes, like it should, when the proxy is not running:

```
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://somewebsite"); //not https
```

Is this still a deficiency in htmlunit? Is there a good workaround or hack to get socks proxy working with https?

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug present in version 2.10 and is now fixed in version 2.11

Comment: I have not gotten a chance to test https with a proxy, but I cannot even get regular https logins to work with 2.11 . I'll try to see if it's something unique about what I'm doing.